# Knowing the type of the template outside the class

Tags: c++, templates

To make it clear, I want to imitate the behaviour of the `value_type` member of `std::vector`.

For example:

```
template <class T>
class foo{
    //some declaration and definition for value_type
};

int main(){
    foo<int> bar;
    bar::value_type x=5; //x is int
}
```

How can I implement it?

Comment: Strictly speaking, what you posted isn't possible, since `bar` is an object. And doesn't support scope resolution.

Comment: You mean I can not infer the type from an object because it compile time operation ? mmmm

Comment: Yes and no. You can't because there is no syntax to do it. And there is no syntax to do it, because it's done statically at compile time, and you'll have access to the objects type anyway.

Comment: You could possibly do `decltype(bar)::value_type`, if your compiler has implemented that (late addition).

Comment: BTW, why do you ask? Trying to solve a problem related to template meta-programming?

Comment: @StoryTeller Simple case where I have templated class called "results" and I know to know the type of the results when i pass set of them to another function

Comment: Than the answers bellow should suffice, I think :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
template <class T>
class foo {
public:
    typedef T value_type;
};
```

BTW: `bar::value_type` is invalid, you should use it as:

```
foo<int>::value_type x = 5; //x is int
```

Answer (score 5):

```
template <class T>
class foo{
    using value_type = T;
};
```

Comment: really! Thanks for very fast answer!